# How to install AASTeX 6.1 (TeX Live 2016, Win 7 x64)

Tags: texlive, installing, aastex

I'm writing my paper with TeX and i need to use `\documentclass{aastex}` and `\usepackage{spr-astr-addons}`. I'm new to LaTeX and i don't know how install new package, wich isn't in the standart repository (i.e. I can't install AASTeX through TeX Live Manager). 
Many thanks and I'm sorry for my bad English (I'm learning English).

Comment: Have you read http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/astr.html?

Comment: Btw: The page mentioned has an email address at the end. Please ask there and *please* complain that these files are not on CTAN - if they were, they would be automagically included in TeXLive.

Comment: And: aastex proper *is* included in TeXLive (install the package `aastex`); only the files from Springer are missing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.